# Stack Exchange Topbar Tools

Tags: script, library, topbar

### About

Ever stared at that *almost*-black<sup>1</sup> bar at the top of the page and thought "not awesome enough"?

**Well, think no longer!** Stack Exchange Topbar Tools is a userscript that contains an extensible framework for making that *almost*-black bar *more awesome*.

With this userscript installed, you can write plugins that

- Change the colour of the bar, and make it float at the top of the viewport or expand to the width of the screen
- Add links to the right side (between your badge counts and the search box), and change their colour
- Give those links (even the default ones) little bubbles like the ones on the left-side icons, to provide notifications of things that need doing
- *lots of other cool stuff that will be implemented sometime in the future*

The getting-started snippet (see end of post) provides plugin initialisation that

- behaves the same way (that is, working) no matter which order things are loaded in
- and won't blow up even if you don't load the underlying library at all!
  <sup>It still won't *work*, though; it just won't blow up.</sup>

#### License

[**The MIT License**](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

Some *really* old versions used the GPL v3, but [a commenter](https://stackapps.com/users/4812/jmort253) made me realise that was not a great idea:

> Just a suggestion, you could make the license MIT or BSD, which are also commercial-friendly. Thus, the code would be open source for everyone. After all, there's nothing wrong with an individual being able to make a profit, especially if it benefits the SE users.

#### Download

[**The library itself**](https://github.com/michaelb958/StackExchangeTopbarTools/raw/v0.2.0/StackExchangeTopbarTools.user.js)

Plugins maintained in the official repository:

- [Basic Config](https://github.com/michaelb958/StackExchangeTopbarTools/raw/v0.2.0/SETT-BasicConfig.user.js)
  Buttons to toggle whether the bar is attached to the top of, and/or spans the full width of, the viewport.
- [Float by Default](https://github.com/michaelb958/StackExchangeTopbarTools/raw/v0.2.0/SETT-Float.user.js)
  You want the thing to float? Enable this!
- [Meta/Main+Chat Links](https://github.com/michaelb958/StackExchangeTopbarTools/raw/v0.2.0/SETT-MetaMainChat.user.js)
  Exactly what it says on the tin. Apparently people liked those links.
- [UTC Clock](https://github.com/michaelb958/StackExchangeTopbarTools/raw/v0.2.0/SETT-UtcClock.user.js)
  Factors in `StackExchange.options.serverTimeOffsetSec`, so it's *actually* the official SE server time!

#### Platform

Fully tested in latest Firefox (26 at time of writing); should theoretically work on Chrome.

### Contact

It's just me, [@michaelb958](https://stackexchange.com/users/1048581/michaelb958?tab=accounts). You can contact me by:

- [Creating an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/michaelb958/StackExchangeTopbarTools/issues). This is the preferred mechanism for providing feedback or suggestions for the library.
- Commenting on or answering this post. Feedback or suggestions provided this way will be accepted.
- Pinging me on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). For general conversation and stuff.
- Emailing me (email address available on [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/michaelb958)). For use in case of emergency.

### Code

Written in JavaScript, with ample use of jQuery.
[**Contribute on GitHub!**](https://github.com/michaelb958/StackExchangeTopbarTools)

#### Really basic getting-started template for writing plugins (from the readme)

```js
function with_jQuery(f) {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
  s.setAttribute('data-with-jquery', '');
  document.head.appendChild(s);
}

with_jQuery(function($) {
  (window.StackExchangeTopbarToolsPluginInit
   = window.StackExchangeTopbarToolsPluginInit
   || []).push(function(SETT) {

    // Your plugin code goes here
    // You can refer to the library object by the shorthand `SETT`

  });
  if (typeof window.StackExchangeTopbarTools === 'object')
    window.StackExchangeTopbarTools.pluginsReady();
});
```

---

<sup>`1` Yes, it's black, but it's actually 14% transparent black, which I consider not-black enough on most SE backgrounds.</sup>

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could make the license MIT or BSD, which are also commercial-friendly. Thus, the code would be open source for everyone. After all, there's nothing wrong with an individual being able to make a profit, especially if it benefits the SE users.